# PHP - can't upload files bigger than 20MB

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a problem with adding multiple files on my server. Everything works fine on smaller files (<20MB). They are uploading on the server and into my data base without any errors or problems. But when I want to add files bigger than 20MB (for example 10 files, 2,2MB each) uploading doesn't work. There is no error, just nothing is sended via _POST. I tried to change php.ini files, but it is still the same problem. 
I've increased:

```
max_execution_time to one hour
max_file_uploads to 100 files
memory_limit to 512M
output_buffering to 30M (earlier I've turned it off)
post_max_size to 64MB
upload_max_filesize to 64M
```

The website is on OVH hosting, so every changes I've made in .user.ini file. 
When I'm trying `phpinfo()` it shows values which I've changed.

Anyone knows any solution?

Comment: do you have log access?

Comment: Show us your upload form, is it set correctly?

Comment: Do you check web-server limits?

Comment: Are you sending multiple files, where total count of these files is more than 20MB?

Comment: I have only .bash_logout, .bash_profile, .bashrc, .forward and .htacces. I haven't access to log. Form is correctly, because I can upload smaller files without any problem. How can I check web-server limits? Yes Lukas Hajdu, I'm sending multiple files, and when total count of these files is more than 20MB, nothing happens (none of my files are uploaded). And when I add line: echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] it shows nothing, so it's not even sended to my upload.php file.

Comment: I've got 2 errors in my logs: (32)Broken pipe: FastCGI: comm with server "/homez.644/patrycja/www/uploader/upload.php" aborted: write failed AND FastCGI: An error happend on Fastcgi processing, fallback to CGI

Answer (score 0):

in your .htaccess file, this allow me to add upto 2 GB

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 2048M
php_value post_max_size 2048M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
```

Comment: Why do you allowing to upload 2GB files on your server?

Comment: Based on client requirement, they are uploading high density videos

Comment: It would be safer to add these limits per script, not globally.

Comment: It doesn't work. I've changed my .htaccess file, and it's still the same. Files aren't sended from form to my upload.php (and still only bigger than 20MB, smaller are sended without any problem)

Comment: Then how does the file come to upload.php, in that case can you put some log and check whether you are getting data on upload.php in case file size is more than 20MB?

Comment: I've got 2 errors in my logs: (32)Broken pipe: FastCGI: comm with server "/homez.644/patrycja/www/uploader/upload.php" aborted: write failed AND FastCGI: An error happend on Fastcgi processing, fallback to CGI